# SQL Server table refreshing through ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a website for a warehouse using ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework. There are over 5000 tools and equipment in this warehouse.

I have a model class like this:

```
public class Tool
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have another table which keeps the log of all of the inputs and outputs of tools which is like:

```
public class Transaction
{        
    public long Id { get; set; }        
    public string FormId { get; set; }               
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }     
    public bool IsInput { get; set; }       // if input 1 if output 0              
    public float Quantity { get; set; }        
    public Tool Item { get; set; }            //equipment
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Each day there will at least be 300 rows added to the `Transaction` table and in 3 years it will be over 300,000 rows. To get the quantity of an individual tool I did something like:

```
database.getTools()
      .where(x => x.Id == ID)
      .where(x => x.IsInput == true)
      .select(x => x.quantity).sum() -   //all inputs for this tool
database.getTools()
      .where(x => x.Id == ID)
      .where(x => x.IsInput == false)
      .select(x => x.quantity).sum();   //all outputs for this tool
```

I am concerned that after sometime (few years) this function will be really time consuming especially if it has to iterate through all tools of the warehouse. One of the best ways is to make a fresh new table at the end of the warehouse counting period and initialize all of the tools with their closing stock quantity. This will make sure that the number of rows of the transaction table do not grow indefinitely.

1. But how to do this? What should I search for?
2. If my approach is not correct please correct me.

One more thing is that this is not the only purpose of the website which means that there are other tables doing some other things that I don't want to be affected by this process, what I mean is I cannot make a new database.

I am new to all of this so please keep it as simple as possible.

Thanks

Comment: If you index your tables properly, 300,000 rows shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: both the tables have self generating id which is incremented by each row. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: A very simple solution is to have 2 (or 3) tables: 1 for transactions like the one you have, 2. "Consolidation", each month you can execute the query for each tool and write the result on this table as a single line. Optionally you can delete the rows on the transactions table otherwise (if you want an history) when you create the transaction rows you write on two table. 3) A month transaction table, truncated each month after consolidation.

Comment: @Max that will do it. Thanks.

Comment: If you want a database that performs well you should understand indexes https://www.dummies.com/programming/sql/how-to-work-with-sql-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

well, First you are using a Database Management System which handles the numbers of rows you mentioned easily.

second, you don't need to use the "where" method two times, you don't even need it.
Also, you don't need "sum" as you filtering using the ID
when you use where to filter by ID  it returns an IEnumerable(list) of type your class that contains one object.

I would use "SingleOrDefault" instead of "Where" method to achieve this, it returns an object for you
Here is an example

```
  Transaction trans =  _context.Transactions.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.Id == ID && x.IsInput == true);
```

where _context is your context object and  Transactions is your DbSet property

Then you can use the object to access the quantity.

```
var quantity = trans.Quantity
```

Comment: The relation between Transaction and Tool is one to many, which means that each tool will have many transactions. So we I use the Sum to add their quantity.

Comment: Regardless of which syntax you use (multiple where methods or one big expression), it boils down to the same SQL.

Comment: could you clarify what "database.getTools()" returns?

Comment: @AbdallahMahmoudHiekal list of all tools in the warehouse, not the quantity. you see the quantity is calculated by the transactions each tool have. lets say I have a tool A ( 3 of it )and I give this tool to warehouse. by doing so a transaction is recorded for tool A and quantity of 3 with input flag =1 to mark that it is input.

Comment: so "database.getTools()" return IEnumerable(list) of "Tool", how could u access this "x.quantity", your class "Tool" dones't  has this property, plz let me know the correct return type of  "database.getTools()", from your code I see the return type of it maybe   IEnumerable(list) of "Transaction" I assumed that in the solution, so if you don't  want to access the context class directly then simply substitute it by your method like this 
  database.getTools().SingleOrDefault(x=> x.Id == ID && x.IsInput == true).Quantity